# ClassCastException in Java 11 but not in Java 8 when using HashMap?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, hashmap, java-11

Please take a look at my code:

```
Object longL = 2548214;
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
map.put("LongNumber", longL);
List<Map<String, Object>> returnlist = new ArrayList(10);
returnlist.add(map);

List<Object> versionMap1 = new ArrayList(10);
versionMap1.add(returnlist);

List<Map<String, String>> docIdVersionNameMap = new ArrayList<>();
docIdVersionNameMap.addAll((List<Map<String, String>>)versionMap1.get(0));

Map<String, String> versionDoc=docIdVersionNameMap.get(0);

Map<String,String> versionDocInfo=new HashMap<String,String>(1);
versionDocInfo.put(versionDoc.get("LongNumber"),"abc");
System.out.println(versionDocInfo.toString());
```

In Java_1.8_60 (Compile & Run) this code is running fine, but when compiled and run in Java 11 it is throwing the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of l
oader 'bootstrap')
        at teststringandlong.Trial.main(Trial.java:35)
```

Are there any changes in Java 11 regarding HashMap?

Comment: I'm getting the same error in Java 8, and it's not surprising - you are trying to put an `Integer` as a key in a `Map<String,String>`.

Comment: Java `1.8_60` is pretty old but still hard to believe it is running correctly. With a bit newer version I got `java version "1.8.0_112" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15) ... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: ...`

Comment: @YassinHajaj as key: `versionDocInfo.put(versionDoc.get("LongNumber"),"abc");`

Comment: @Eran, you're right indeed. What's strange is that the same exact code works on `ideone.com [HotSpot 8u112]` and `JDoodle [JDK 10.0.1]`. https://ideone.com/296BMB & https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler (just copy past it with correct imports)

Comment: I don't get the close votes. Please don't close it, this code works on multiple platforms, and on my PC locally too.

Answer (score 18):

The `ClassCastException` being thrown is correct. Not having it thrown was caused by a bug in `javac`, which was fixed in JDK 9 by [JDK-8058199](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8058199). Your code is technically relying on heap pollution not being picked up, so it was never guaranteed to not break.

Basically, in Java 11 (but starting from 9), an extra cast is inserted after getting the value for `"LongNumber"` from the map on the second to last line. This:

```
versionDocInfo.put(versionDoc.get("LongNumber"),"abc");
```

Is compiled as:

```
versionDocInfo.put((String) versionDoc.get("LongNumber"),"abc");
```

---

When compiling your code with `javac 1.8.0_162`, the bytecode for the second to last line is:

```
 114: aload         7
 116: aload         6
 118: ldc           #6                  // String LongNumber
 120: invokeinterface #16,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/Map.get:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
 125: ldc           #17                 // String abc
 127: invokeinterface #7,  3            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Map.put:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Notice that there is no `checkcast` instruction after `120:`. However, when using `javac 9.0.4`:

```
 114: aload         7
 116: aload         6
 118: ldc           #6                  // String LongNumber
 120: invokeinterface #16,  2           // InterfaceMethod java/util/Map.get:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
 125: checkcast     #17                 // class java/lang/String
 128: ldc           #18                 // String abc
 130: invokeinterface #7,  3            // InterfaceMethod java/util/Map.put:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Notice that there is a `checkcast` instruction at `125:`.

This instruction makes the difference, as it basically does an extra type check after getting the value from the `versionDoc` map. Basically doing this:

```
versionDocInfo.put((String) versionDoc.get("LongNumber"),"abc");
```

In Java 11 (starting  from 9).

---

As noted in the comments; the type of the value for `"LongNumber"` is `Integer`, which is inside a `Map<String, String>` due to the unchecked cast a few lines earlier:

```
docIdVersionNameMap.addAll((List<Map<String, String>>) versionMap1.get(0));
```

Where you indirectly cast a `Map<String, Object>` to a `Map<String, String>`, even though one of the values is an `Integer`. The difference is only that there's an extra cast to check the type after getting the value from the map.

Note that the missing `checkcast` was a bug in `javac`, so compiling with a different compiler, or different versions of `javac` could result in different behavior.

Comment: How can we explain that it runs on Java 10 on jdoodle.com and also that some of us have the code failing on Java 8 and some not?

Comment: @YassinHajaj Well, it's really `javac` that's at fault, not `java`, so if you're using e.g. Eclipse to compile the class you might get different behavior. If you can, you should check the byte code with `javap -c ...`

Comment: @YassinHajaj I'm not sure about jdoodle.com, using the same version of Java 10 I am getting the CCE being thrown. Must be something about their setup... Testing with e.g. `var  x = 10` this does not compile on jdoodle.com, so I guess they're using `javac` from JDK 8 to compile, and then running with java 10.

Comment: Alright thanks, checkin the bytecode locally, it's indeed not invoking the checkcast operation ! Thanks, this is very interesting :)